# Multiple selection reading from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, html

is there any way to make three drop down (or similar) selections of records from three different 
columns in one database `table A` and than insert my choice into another `table B` using PHP code?

- First selection is reading and presenting data from column A
- Second selection is reading and presenting data from column B
- Third selection is reading and presenting data from column C

after my choices I would like to post my selection into `Table B` with proper conditions.

---

**MySQL `TABLE A`**

```
    -------------------------------------------------
    | col A | col B | col C | col D | col E | col F |
    -------------------------------------------------
    ENGLAND |       |       |       |       |       |
    FRANCE  | 0     | 1     | 1     | Nicky | Adams |
    RUSSIA  | 1     | 2     | 0     | Ricky | Gommy |
    DENMARK | 0     | 3     | 1     | Tommy | Rommy |
    GERMANY | 0     | 4     | 1     | Bobby | Biggy |
    FINLAND | 1     | 5     | 0     | Timmy | Zyggy |
```

---

**MySQL `TABLE B`**

```
    
    -----------------
    | col D | col E | 
    -----------------
    | Nicky | Adams |
```

Comment: What's the problem ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: My php skill only allowed my to make selection box writing by me, I don't no how to do active options. Active as inserted (not writing by me, showing whole row options) from columns and active for my choices

Comment: Is thare is a possible to work? 

`$x=mysql_query("SELECT coL A
FROM TABLE A "); 
$y=mysql_query("SELECT coL B
FROM TABLE A "); 
$z=mysql_query("SELECT coL C
FROM TABLE A "); `

`<select name="FIRST CHOICE">
  <option value="<?php echo $x ?>"></option>
  <option value="<?php echo $y ?>"></option>
  <option value="<?php echo $z ?>"></option>
</select>`

`<select name="SECOND CHOICE">
  <option value="<?php echo $y ?>"></option>
</select>`

`<select name="THIRD CHOICE">
  <option value="<?php echo $z ?>"></option>
</select>`

BUT how to force my selection to insert my result into TABLE B

Comment: You have to handle the event on the HTML control with Javascript ..

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion, I will try my best unfortunately with my lack of Javascript knowledge it takes times;) Thank You once again.

Answer (score 0):

you must fetching values from tableA first
then insert it in tableB
then drop it from tableA

Comment: That is not exacly my problem, I want to find out how to call the row in the drop down list:

[`<select name="formGender">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="M">Male</option>
  <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
</p>`]

but the optins should be the options offering by the table columns.